# Hang section number, but not subsection number in Memoir

Tags: sectioning, memoir

I use the memoir class to control my document. I have placed the section numbering in the margin with `\hangsecnum`, but I don't want the subsection and subsubsection numbering in the margin.

How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the sectioning hooks would be an easy way:

```
\setsechook{\hangsecnum}
\setsubsechook{\defaultsecnum}
\setsubsubsechook{\defaultsecnum}
```

Edit: here's a minimal working example, according to the comments:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\addtocounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setsechook{\hangsecnum}
\setsubsechook{\defaultsecnum}
\setsubsubsechook{\defaultsecnum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\section{Section heading}
\subsection{Subsection heading}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection heading}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I thought it worked but \setsechook{\hangsecnum} do not work

Comment: @aagaard: "do not work" isn't a sufficient problem description. Better post error message, description of behavior, a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). I added one showing how it works.

Comment: I found out, that there is some compatibility issues with this package: titlesec. When it is included, it meshed up the indent.

Comment: Why do you use [titlesec](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) in this context?

Comment: To control the vertical space between the section title and the text.

Comment: @aagard: Section 6.9 (Predefined heading styles, p. 112ff) of the [memoir](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) manual shows how to do that in this class.