# Hanging styled section numbers in memoir class

Tags: sectioning, formatting, color, memoir

I would like hanging, styled section numbers while using the memoir class.  The answer [customizing section formatting using memoir class (color and numbering)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56004/customizing-section-formatting-using-memoir-class-color-and-numbering) explains how to style just the numbers, and the answer [Hang section number, but not subsection number in Memoir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9459/hang-section-number-but-not-subsection-number-in-memoir) explains how to hang the section number.  However, when I attempt to combine these, my styling vanishes!

The commands I am using are:

```
\setsecnumformat{\color{blue}\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
\setsechook{\hangsecnum}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: As you can see in jons answer, `\hangsecnum` is an already defined secnumformat. So line two kills the format you just set. You can just copy the inner code from jons answer, you're basically just missing `\llap`, then you do not need to redefine `\hangsecnum `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want. It simply modifies `\hangsecnum` to be blue for the section number.

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\hangsecnum}{%
  \def\@seccntformat##1{%
    \makebox[0pt][r]{%
      \color{blue}%
      \csname the##1\endcsname
      \quad
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\setsechook{\hangsecnum}
\setsubsechook{\defaultsecnum}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}
\subsection{First Subsection}
\subsubsection{First Subsubsection}

I would like hanging, styled section numbers while using the memoir
class. The answer customizing section formatting using memoir class
(color and numbering) explains how to style just the numbers, and the
answer Hang section number, but not subsection number in Memoir
explains how to hang the section number. However, when I attempt to
combine these, my styling vanishes!

\section{Second Section}
\subsection{Second Subsection}
\subsubsection{Second Subsubsection}

I would like hanging, styled section numbers while using the memoir
class. The answer customizing section formatting using memoir class
(color and numbering) explains how to style just the numbers, and the
answer Hang section number, but not subsection number in Memoir
explains how to hang the section number. However, when I attempt to
combine these, my styling vanishes!

\end{document}
```

Comment: Avoid `\llap` in the wild. And resetting the color is not needed, because `\makebox` groups its contents. The fact that `memoir` uses `\llap` in `\hangsecnum` is irrelevant (it's wrong to begin with).

Comment: @egreg -- that redefinitely looks tidier, thanks. (I was simply trying to mimic -- and show -- the original definition of `\hangsecnum`.) Not that I use them much, but is there a simple reason why `\llap` (and `\rlap`?) should be avoided?

Comment: Unlike `\makebox`, `\llap` and `\rlap` don't start horizontal mode, if found in vertical mode. Not a real problem there, but when not writing package code it's better to use the safer version; `\makebox` is also color savvy, which `\llap` may not be.